# IIS Website accessible only over a wired connection

Tags: .net, iis, wifi, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a website I've deployed on a virtual server for testing over my company's local domain only. I can access the website just fine over any wired connection, but if I try and navigate to the server over a wifi connection I get a timeout error, the server doesn't seem to have any record of a connection even being attempted. I've added Windows Firewall rules and even turned off the firewall completely. I can PING the server just fine over any connection, but the connection always times out over wifi.

I'm running this on Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5. 
The .Net Framework I'm using is v4.0.30319.

Thanks in advance for the help, and let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: when you are on wifi are you able to telnet on port 80 ? i.e. Telnet <server name> 80

Comment: Telnet doesn't seem to be working over wifi either, but it will on the wired connection.

Comment: Definitely something over the network is blocking your requests. Can you check your browser's proxy settings (although not directly related to the issue). You need to take a simultaneous network trace and see which IP packets are getting dropped  Your network admin should be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ravi. This ended up being a DNS error, apparently the DHCP server wasn't configured right. Appreciate the help!